# How to pass parameter class object c# to c++ typedef union struct in unmanaged dll import?

Tags: c#, c++, class, struct, dllimport

I want to call unmanaged c++ program with struct as parameter.

**The c++ struct is like down below.**

```
typedef union {
    BYTE byBuffer[32];

    struct {
        union {
        DWORD dwOptionFlag;
            struct {
                unsigned BIT_IGNOREEXSTOP : 1;
                unsigned BIT_USE_CUSTOMACCDEC : 1;
            };
        } flagOption;
        WORD wCustomAccDecTime;
    };
} VELOCITY_OPTION_EX;
```

**Function parameter documentation in c++**

```
int FAS_MoveVelocityEx(
    BYTE nPortNo,
    BYTE iSlaveNo,
    DWORD lVelocity,
    int iVelDir,
    VELOCITY_OPTION_EX* lpExOption
);
```

**C# code I use to import the dll function**

```
[DllImport("EziMOTIONPlusR.dll")]
public static extern EziServoResult FAS_MoveVelocityEx
    (byte nPortNo, byte iSlaveNo, long lVelocity, int iVelDir, out VELOCITY_OPTION_EX lpExOption);
```

How to create the class from c# that match VELOCITY_OPTION_EX in c++?

**Note:** I only have the documentation + dll library and it's written in c++.

Comment: I have had to do a similar thing with the windows DCB interface. The problem is with the bit fields and the union. You will remove the union from the structure, and just use the dwOptionFlag. You will then define the bitmasks corresponding to each bitfield and mask that into/outof the dwOptionFlag field.

Comment: But how can I deal with the first union and register the struct inside it?

Comment: the structure VELOCITY_OPTION_EX is an array of 32 bytes. Of those 32 bytes, the first 6 have a meaning for you. These are the dwOptionFlag of 4 bytes at offset 0, and the wCustomAccDecTime of 2 bytes at offset 4. The rest of the content remains undescribed.

Comment: so I can use [FieldOffset(offset)] for every property. is that right?